# jQuery - reverse action

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

First of all I know that the code is ugly, but I am a beginner with JS, so please understand me.

This is what I have done to this time. What I have to do? Step by step:

1. click on #img1 and then loop start...
2. #img1 change from green to red image and #text1 too (from green to red)
3. then after some time #img1 and #text1 back too default values (all green)
4. #img2 and #text2 do all the same (automatic, without click)
5. all the same to the last #img5 and #text5

Between changing every li should be few seconds pause. Please help me!

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="li-1"><img id="img1" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text1">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-2"><img id="img2" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text2">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-3"><img id="img3" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text3">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-4"><img id="img4" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text4">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-5"><img id="img5" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text5">Text</p></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var count = 0;
function images() {
  if (count == 0) {
    $('#img1').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text1').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 1) {
    $('#img2').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text2').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 2) {
    $('#img3').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text3').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 3) {
    $('#img4').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text4').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 4) {
    $('#img5').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text5').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  }
}
setInterval(images, 1000);
```

```js
var count = 0;

function images() {
  if (count == 0) {
    $('#img1').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text1').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 1) {
    $('#img2').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text2').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 2) {
    $('#img3').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text3').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 3) {
    $('#img4').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text4').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 4) {
    $('#img5').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text5').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  }
}
setInterval(images, 1000);
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0 250px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
ul .li-1 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul .li-1 img {
  width: 100px;
}
ul .li-1 p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #00875b;
  font-size: 38.89px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul .li-2 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul .li-2 img {
  width: 100px;
}
ul .li-2 p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #00875b;
  font-size: 38.89px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul .li-3 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul .li-3 img {
  width: 100px;
}
ul .li-3 p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #00875b;
  font-size: 38.89px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul .li-4 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul .li-4 img {
  width: 100px;
}
ul .li-4 p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #00875b;
  font-size: 38.89px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul .li-5 {
  list-style: none;
}
ul .li-5 img {
  width: 100px;
}
ul .li-5 p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #00875b;
  font-size: 38.89px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="li-1">
    <img id="img1" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" />
    <p id="text1">Text</p>
  </li>
  <li class="li-2">
    <img id="img2" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" />
    <p id="text2">Text</p>
  </li>
  <li class="li-3">
    <img id="img3" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" />
    <p id="text3">Text</p>
  </li>
  <li class="li-4">
    <img id="img4" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" />
    <p id="text4">Text</p>
  </li>
  <li class="li-5">
    <img id="img5" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" />
    <p id="text5">Text</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Change to this image -->
<img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png" />
```

Comment: Live: http://codepen.io/ZAM666/pen/akGdVw

Comment: Just change the `setInterval` at the bottom from 1000 (1 second) to 3000 (3 seconds). The code seems to run as you want it to.

Comment: OP. sorry i don't quite understand what you are looking for. Are you trying to make the lights go from green to red in left to right direction, then back from red to green from right to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to apply green circle and text to element before when you are looping. I cleared your code a bit as well

Working solution:

```js
var count = 0;
function images() {
  if (count == 0) {
    toRed('#img1','#text1');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 1) {
    toRed('#img2','#text2');
    toGreen('#img1','#text1');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 2) {
    toRed('#img3','#text3');
    toGreen('#img2','#text2');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 3) {
    toRed('#img4','#text4');
    toGreen('#img3','#text3');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 4) {
    toRed('#img5','#text5');
    toGreen('#img4','#text4');
    count++;
  }
}
$('#img1').on('click',function() {
  setInterval(images, 1000);
});

function toGreen(image, text) {
    $(image).attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
    $(text).css('color', 'green');
}
function toRed(image, text) {
    $(image).attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $(text).css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="li-1"><img width = '50px' id="img1" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text1">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-2"><img width = '50px' id="img2" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text2">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-3"><img width = '50px' id="img3" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text3">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-4"><img width = '50px' id="img4" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text4">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-5"><img width = '50px' id="img5" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text5">Text</p></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working solution also, but i wrote it like u did above:

```
var count = 0;
function images() {
  if (count == 0) {
    $('#img1').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text1').css('color', 'red');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 1) {
    $('#img2').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text2').css('color', 'red');

    $('#img1').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
    $('#text1').css('color', 'green');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 2) {
    $('#img3').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
    $('#text3').css('color', 'red');

    $('#img2').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
    $('#text2').css('color', 'green');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 3) {
    $('#img4').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text4').css('color', 'red');

    $('#img3').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
    $('#text3').css('color', 'green');
    count++;
  } else if (count == 4) {
    $('#img5').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
    $('#text5').css('color', 'red');

    $('#img4').attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
    $('#text4').css('color', 'green');
    count++;
  }
}
setInterval(images, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. How to start this loop after click on #img1?

Comment: Okay, thank you. It is very easy, but hard to understand at the beginning ;)

Comment: I have a problem. I have every image different to change:
1 to 1_2,
2 to 2_2,
3 to 3_2,
4 to 4_2,
5 to 5_2.

How to change the code?

Comment: just change parameters toRed('#img1','#text1'); to -> toRed('#img1_2','#text1'); @ZAM666

Comment: in every <li> I have got different img. Also I have to change every img to every different img. In sum, there are 2 images for one <li>. So, how to do this? I have to write 10 functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by using your counter. By storing a temp variable and using that to set your previous image back to green you can make your code a lot smaller.

```js
// Create variables in global scope
var count;
var temp;
var interval;
var click = true;
function images() {
  // Chnage to red
  $('#img' +(count)).attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/red-circle-icon-1.png");
  $('#text' +(count)).css('color', 'red');
  
  // Turn back to green
  $('#img' +(temp)).attr('src', "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png");
  $('#text' +(temp)).css('color', 'green');

  if(temp == 5){ // If we have completed the entire cycle then stop the interval. Set to 5 becuase there are 5 images
    clearInterval(interval);
    click = true; // Cycle has finished so we can allow users to click on the image
  }
temp = count;
count++;
}

$('#img1').click(function(){
  if(click){ // This stops people from spamming the image button and breaking the pattern
  // Set count equal to 1 since your first div has and id of #img1 
  count = 1;
  // Set temp equal to zero as it has to be one less than your counter value to set the previous value back to the green image
  temp = 0;
  // setInterval is now assigned to a variable to we can stop the intervals latter if we want to be able to do the same action again when we click on the first image...
  interval = setInterval(images, 1000);
    click = false; // Set click to false so they can't click anymore
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="li-1"><img id="img1" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text1">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-2"><img id="img2" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text2">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-3"><img id="img3" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text3">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-4"><img id="img4" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text4">Text</p></li>
  <li class="li-5"><img id="img5" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-icon-28.png" /><p id="text5">Text</p></li>
</ul>
```

If you read the documentation you should be able to understand what is going on. Here is a codepen to see the changes with your css/sass: http://codepen.io/clapynick/pen/LkmyqK

Comment: Thanks a lot for "better" code, but Aleksandar was first and I decided to select him.

Comment: @ZAM666 Ha ha. No problem

Comment: I have a problem. I have every image different to change:
1 to 1_2,
2 to 2_2,
3 to 3_2,
4 to 4_2,
5 to 5_2.

How to change the code?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do... @ZAM666